# Python simple loop of averages only returns first item

Tags: python, control-flow

I wrote a code to calculate an average, but it takes only the first item in the list.
I want to input a list of key=value and it should add all the values and then divide by the total number, so it gives me the average.

```
def average_price_petrol(**args):
result = 0
total = 0
for key,value in args.items():
        result += value
        total +=1
        return result/total

average_price_petrol(aral = 1.799, bft = 1.629, esso = 1.799, shell = 1.829, jet = 1.719)
```

Comment: First thing first - please fix the *indentation* of code.

Comment: BTW, be aware of that using *float* will lose the *precision*?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The code as posted will actually generate an error. You did not report an error, so I suspect the problem is the position of the return statement.  As shown the function will exit on the 1st iteration of the loop. Indent return to the same level as the word for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the already mentioned indentation issue for `return` which causes the function to return on the very first loop iteration, you do not need to iterate over `args.items()` as you don't care about the keys.

```
def average_price_petrol(**args):
    result = 0
    total = 0
    for value in args.values():
        result += value
        total += 1
    return result / total
```

And this can be simplified to:

```
def average_price_petrol(**args):
    return sum(args.values()) / len(args)
```

Comment: This post should be marked as *accepted* - it explains clearly about the OP issues and offer some improvement as well.  +1

Answer (score 2):

You need to indent the code properly.

```
def average_price_petrol(**args):
    result = 0
    total = 0
    for key,value in args.items():
        result += value
        total +=1
    return result/total
```

Python uses spaces to determine scopes so your code would loop through the first argument and then return the average before the loop has finished

Comment: This answer would be improved if you elaborate on why the indentation of the return statement is causing the behavior the OP is seeing.

Comment: @Chris added explanation